# Showing a subgroup contains the identity element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ along with $+$. Show that $H$ defined by $H=\{f:f(x)=0 \text{ for all } x \in [0,1]\}$ is a subgroup.

I am able to show $H$ has inverses and that $H$ is closed. But how do I show $H$ is nonempty? Any argument I use would begin with "let $x\in H$..." and isn't this begging the question of emptiness?

Comment: Just provide an explicit example of a function in $H$ (hint: You know the neutral element needs to be there).

Comment: Ok thanks, will it always be the case to choose to find the neutral element?

Comment: @Moz In many cases it's the obvious choice to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a concrete example
$$
f(x)=0\;\forall\;x\in\mathbb R
$$
to show it's non-empty (which is in fact the identity element).